# Are there textbooks that include the fact that an isomorphism depends on the choice of a universe?

Tags: logic, reference-request

I cannot remember much, so I apologise for the vague question in advance. I previously have glanced at being written that an isomorphism depends on the choice of a universe and so the concept of an isomorphism is not perfect as it of "a same". I would like to learn more about this fact, are there any textbooks that give a detailed description? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what sense are you using the word ”universe”? A possible interpretation is a category, and of course the notion of whether a map is an isomorphism depends on which category you are in.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I construe the meaning of a universe as a model of ZFC. If the source I have glanced at, however, use this word at a different meaning, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague to the point of being unanswerable. We don't even know isomorphisms of what you are talking about. Put yourself in the shoes of someone reading what you wrote: do you really think they would be able to know what you mean?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember much, so I think too those who can answer this question are only some people already know this fact. I wish I could explain more detail...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Wilfrid Hodges comments on this in his *[Model Theory](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511551574)*:

> Compare the two relations $\simeq$ (isomorphism) and $\equiv$ (elementary equivalence) between structures. In one sense isomorphism is a more intrinsic property of structures, because it's defined directly in terms of structural properties, whereas $\equiv$ involves a language. But in another sense elementary equivalence is more intrinsic, because the existence of an isomorphism can depend on
> some subtle questions about the surrounding universe of sets. (p. 94)

He gives an example of vector spaces, which may not be isomorphic in a given model, but may "become" isomorphic in a forcing extension that collapses their cardinals into the same one. He also uses this to motivate the introduction of the back-and-forth technique as a relation that is intrinsic (not dependent on the universe of sets) and language-independent.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. I appriciate your kindness which let you answer this extremely vague question. I will search for Wilfrid Hodges' Model Theory.

Comment: @beginner_nt - No worries. it just so happens that this passage had stricken me when I first read it, so it was easy to recall it in the context of your question.

Comment: @beginner_nt: If you are on a university or other institutional network, then you should be able to access the Hodges book here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511551574  If you don’t have an institutional affiliation, you may be able to find it through SciHub.